# C++ program not compiling properly [cout statement ] after certain line

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and using minGW version 6.3.0-1. I am not able to compile this code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r, c, a[5][5];
    cout << "Test loop";

    for (int x = 1; x <= 6; ++x)
    {
        cout << "Value of variable x is: " << x << endl;
    }

    cout << "Test loop ends" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns:";
    cin >> r >> c;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
            cout << "Enter the array element:";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "The array you entered:" << "\n order:" << r << "x" << c;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Also please help find out which C++ standard im using currently.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please use formal, proper English in your post.

Comment: minGW version 6.3.0-1

Comment: I'm not getting any error that's the problem after entering the array the window closes it doesn't show the final op that is displaying the 2d array!!
**edit ** the input is a matrix and the output is displaying the matrix.

Comment: [edit] the question to add what is the input, current and expected output.

Comment: "... which c++ standard im using currently?" - If you are using Turbo C++, then the answer is *none*. Turbo C++ is outdated several decades and implements a version of C++ that predates even the first standardized one (C++98). Please don't use Turbo C++.

Comment: @Sinister Why did you revert my edit?

Comment: See I mentioned I'm new here!! But you people are cutting main parts of the question I only gave permission for the first edit not for the latter one! And then you came up with a very short one but I don't feel it's correct

Comment: I cut whats irrelevant for your question. Its irrelevant which compiler you used before MinGW. Its irrelevant which editor you use to write your code. Instead I added version information about your MinGW that you have provided in the comments, which is in contrary RELEVANT for the question which standard of C++ you are using. Other than that I just translated to standard english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     return 0;
>     getch();
> }
> ```

Your `main()` returns before waiting for a character using `getch()`. Switch those two lines:

```
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> Also please help find out which C++ standard im using currently.

If you don't specify `-std` when you compile your code, gcc 6.3 defaults to -`std=gnu++14` which means you are using C++14 with GNU extensions. See the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) for further details.

Comment: thank you so much I didn't notice this at all. and also i have an another problem which is when i try to compile and run it from the txt editor itself it goes like an infinite loop!! why is it so??

Comment: @Sinister Stop help vampirism  putting unrelated questions in comments at answers please! Ask another question instead.

Comment: @Sinister [so] is not a discussion forum. Each question is a question. Comments are only for suggesting improvements and pointing out errors (see help center), **not** for asking another question.